# Is there recommended way to handle Twitter API error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm creating a Twitter related web service. So Twitter API is called in many points in it.
I know the rate limit error can be handled by `rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests`.

But to write in every place `begin` and `rescue` syntax is little troublesome and error prone.

When the error happens I want to show a error message in view and make the twitter request method return `nil`.

I'm using twitter gem and using like this.

```
 # app/models/user.rb
 def twitter
    @twitter ||= Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: access_token, oauth_token_secret: access_secret)
 end
```

How can I implement like this?

Besides this is only what comes up to my mind, if there is a better way I'll follow the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Just rescue the error and return nil in your method:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def twitter
  @twitter ||= Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: access_token, oauth_token_secret: access_secret)
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests
  nil
end
```

Now the method itself will return nil when your error occurs.

Then in your controller, you can set the flash if the twitter method returns nil (you could also choose something more descriptive than nil).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I noticed now the rescue doesn't catch the `Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests`. Have you any idea why is that?

Comment: If the line `@twitter ||= Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: access_token, oauth_token_secret: access_secret)` is raising the error  `Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests`, then that rescue will catch it. Can you be more specific about what is happening?

Comment: I call a method like `user.twitter.list_owned` in another place of code. Then error is not caught by the rescue statement.

Comment: Are you sure the error is spelled `Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests`?  You could also try `rescue Twitter::Error` or `rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error`

Comment: I tried both code that you showed me. But both failed to catch the error.

Comment: Your error is somewhere else then. See an official example here: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/b082ed06667c10b0a31797d46a2512c493d21468/examples/RateLimiting.md

Comment: From beginning I'm asking how to handle the rate limit errors that happens many points in a rails project. But thanks anyway. If there is no succinct way to accomplish that I'll write `begin` and `rescue` statement in every places.

Comment: I'd like to help you understand what is happening, but you need to give more about your errors.  I just tested the example I gave and it definitely works, so your error is elsewhere.

Comment: I think I need more practice to separate the problems. Maybe I'll ask it again then. Thanks for your help!